# Mi pag web no no hace responsive cuando lo veo desde el movil

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, responsive

estoy en mi **login** desde mi movil y se ve exactamente igual que el ordenador, pero claro en el movil esta **mal** : las letras muy pequeñas, mucho margen, etc..

Mi codigo del login es este:

```
<?php 
    session_start();

 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <!-- CSS BOOTSTRAP -->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
 -->
 <?php include_once 'partials/bootstrap_css.php' ?>
    <!-- CSS 'FULL' -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos/full.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <form class="tema_principal" method="POST" action="procesos/iniciar_sesion_usuario.php">
                  <div class="form-group"  >
                    <h2>Inicio de sesion</h2>

                    <label>Usuario/Email</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuario" name="usuario_email" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre de usuario o email">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Contraseña</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Introduce tu contraseña">
                    <?php 
                        if (isset($_SESSION['error'])) {
                        echo "<label style='color:red'>El usuario/email o contraseña son <b>erroneos</b></label>";

                        }
                     ?>
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Iniciar Sesion</button>
                </form>
                <label>¿No tienes cuenta?<a style="color:green !important" href="register.php"><b style="color:green;">Registrate</b></a></label>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>





<?php include_once 'partials/bootstrap_jquery.php' ?>

</body>
</html>
```

En teoria la clase `col` poniendo sus `col-sm-4` y eso te deberia mas o menos hacer algo, pero me lo pinta **exactamente igual que la version de pc**

El `@media` no lo estoy usando porque eso lo lleva **intrinseco** el bootstrap no ? solo se toca si quieres alterarlo

Comment: Creo que te hace falta esta etiqueta meta justo después de la etiqueta del `metacharset` mira `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`

Comment: Exacto, eso era. Muchas gracias !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola te falto agregar este meta en tu código

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

y te recomiendo que también coloques este

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
```

Comment: Si, te lo agradeceria, la segunda no se que es.

Comment: La primera es para que la pagina este no este escalada a un tamaño de computador para que los estilos carguen correctamente

Comment: La segunda permiten al navegador mostrar las páginas web que no cumplen con los estándares como si corrieran en versiones anteriores de IE.

Comment: si te sirvieron los metas?